# Noip connection closed by remote host error Ubuntu shh

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh

I'm trying to setup a home server. I want to be able to ssh into it from a non local source so I setup noip. At the moment, noip's port checker says that port 22 on the ip is open and running and I can ssh into the server through the local Ip address. When I try to ssh by using the given non local one though, I get either a connection closed by remote host error, or a connection closed by peer error. Any help in this would be greatly appreciated.

```
ssh -p 22 "Merthew.ddns.net" -v
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to merthew.ddns.net [208.87.51.60] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/alephnull/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/alephnull/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/alephnull/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/alephnull/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/alephnull/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/alephnull/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/alephnull/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/alephnull/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

Comment: looks like the user is missing. Usually would be 
    ssh someName -p 22 "Merthew.ddns.net" -v
without the user it uses the user your coming from. they have to match. Also prob will not let you in as root w/o chaning sshd_conf 
also do two or more -vvv

Comment: Even when I add the username@merthew.ddns.net it gives me the same error.

Comment: So you set up noip, but did you configure port forwarding in your router/firewall correctly?

Comment: Yes, like i said, the port checker verified the there is a service running on port 22. At the moment I'm thinking it has something to do with the noip settings as I can connect locally but remote doesn't work.